# Union of two tables in SQL with new Unique IDS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a union between two tables, each table has the same unique primary key (Module ID). I would like to like to make a new unique primary key out of column Module ID, as it currently contains duplicates.

How can I make the Module ID following the union count upwards from the maximum of the first Module ID? So in short, how can I make the Module ID unique following the union?

```
set identity_insert dpm.Module on

insert into dpm.Module
(
        dpm.Module.[Module ID],
        dpm.Module.[Module Xbrl Schema Ref]
)

select 
        dpm.Module.[Module ID],
        dpm.Module.[Module Xbrl Schema Ref]
from [DPM].[Module]
union
select
        dpm.Module.[Module ID],
        replace(dpm.Module.[Module Xbrl Schema Ref],'.xsd','_bbk.xsd') as [Module Xbrl Schema Ref]
from
[DPM].[Module]
```

Comment: So, what is your question here? You forgot to ask one! :)

Comment: Hope its clearer now ;)

Comment: Why not not use `set identity_insert dpm.Module on` and then exclude the ID from the `INSERT`? The new table will then create a new ID for every row. You seem to be trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I tryed that. But i get this error: Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Module' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: That error message is telling you ***are*** using `set identity_insert dpm.Module on`... You need to switch it off if you're already turned it on.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!